# Populate Text Area using ajax with array items separated by comma

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In my rails app, a page have a text area which is supposed to get populated from the instance variable(having contact_no column). The text area should get populated with all contact no. separated by commas. I am using ajax and updating the div content with the .js.erb file. Now I want to populate the content of text area from the instance variable. How to do this?

text area

```
<div id="result_div">
      <%= f.text_field :sent_to %>
</div>
```

.js.erb file content

```
$("#result_div").html('Hello');
```

This code is simply showing "Hello" in the target div. But I want to populate the text area with the contact numbers in the instance variable @contact.
Note : @contact is an instance variable of model and not an array of contact_no

Comment: Do you have any code that you can share (in case it is not classified, of course)?

Comment: @suslov edited the question with the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
$("#result_div textarea").val("<%= @contact.map(&:parents_contact_no).join(', ') %>");
```

Comment: I tried it, but the text area  doesn't change. Its blank only and giving out the console error (parents_contact_no is the column name)
undefined method `parents_contact_no' for #<Student::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000005308d88>):

Comment: @AjeetKhan: can you update your answer with the output of `@contact.inspect`?

Comment: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Student id: 3, enrollment_no: "6", roll_no: "544", address: "4gfdgfdg", father_name: "sgfdgdfs", mother_name: "sfgfdgs", parents_contact_no: "sfgdfsg", additional_contact_no: "sfdgdfsg", parents_email: "sgfgfd@gmail.com", student_contact_no: "234335435345", alumni: true, created_at: "2015-06-16 19:15:26", updated_at: "2015-06-16 19:15:26", organization_id: 4, class_name: "KG2">]>

Comment: @contact is an instance variable of a model

Comment: I tried that too but the content of text area is still blank

Comment: the output is correct i.e. ["456565"]
But the text area is not getting populated with this result

Comment: @AjeetKhan: then `@contact.map(&:parents_contact_no).join(', ')`? Is there any error in the console?

Comment: There is no error in the console. console is saying the .js.erb file is rendered. I guess the problem is with the text area. May be with the div id or something like that

Answer (score 0):

It's an `erb` file so you can include Ruby code...

```
$("#result_div").html('<%= @contact %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `.js.erb` file you can still access your instance variables. So you might be able to do something like this :

```
$("#result_div").html("#{@instance.contact_no.join(',')}");
```